# Why doesn't `date +%F_%T` work in crontab?

Tags: cron

When I use time and date at the end of a crontab line like `` backup`date
+%F_%T`.sql `` or like `` backup`date%d%m%y`.sql ``, my crontab command doesn't work. But when I remove it, it works perfectly.

Why doesn't it work when I use time and date like `date%d%m%y`?

Comment: The formatting is wrong and very hard to read. Please fix it, and include the exact commands you're running and the exact contents of your crontab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to escape every % and you should also use a little different syntax with date. So e.g. this one will work just fine:

```
`date "+\%d\%m\%y"`.sql
```